# Joomla String to URL Hyperlink

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a Joomla extension which populates data from a table. The data contains URL strings (starting with `https://`, `http://`, `www.`).

These strings are not auto hyperlinked and are shown in plain text format on frontend.

How can I get them auto hyperlinked?

TIA.

Comment: Hi S R, you're going to have to modify that extension to include the `anchor` tags or write a script to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Is there a javascript way to do this in <head> section of the website?

Comment: That depends on the template you're using but doing so would add the script to every page of the website & not just the pages that the extension is visible on. [Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/) is a great library for this functionality.

Comment: I use an extension System - EasyScriptPro, this allows to add the script on certain pages & not all. I was wondering if there is a readymade plugin for this purpose.

Comment: @Daniel you just helped me in a quick way. While googling, I found CloudFlare CDN has got the app for Autolinker.js. I have just enabled it and all the URLs are now hyperlinked. Thank you! :)

Comment: That's great @SR!